# Find duplicate values in R

Tags: r

I have a table with 21638 unique* rows:

```
vocabulary <- read.table("http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Applied-Regression-2E/datasets/Vocabulary.txt", header=T)
```

This table has five columns, the first of which holds the respondent ID numbers. I want to check if any respondents appear twice, or if all respondents are unique.

To count unique IDs I can use

```
length(unique(vocabulary$id))
```

and to check if there are any duplicates I might do

```
length(unique(vocabulary$id)) == nrow(vocabulary)
```

which returns `TRUE`, if there are no duplicates (which there aren't).

**My question:**

Is there a direct way to return the values or line numbers of duplicates?

**Some further explanation:**

There is an interpretation problem with using the function `duplicated()`, because is only returns the duplicates in the strict sense, excluding the "originals". For example, `sum(duplicated(vocabulary$id))` or `dim(vocabulary[duplicated(vocabulary$id),])[1]` might return "5" as the number of duplicate rows. The problem is that if you only know the number of duplicates, you won't know how many rows they duplicate. Does "5" mean that there are five rows with one duplicate each, or that there is one row with five duplicates? And since you won't have the IDs or line numbers of the duplicates, you wouldn't have any means of finding the "originals".

---

**I know there are no duplicate IDs in this survey, but it is a good example, because using any of the answers given elsewhere to this question, like `duplicated(vocabulary$id)` or `table(vocabulary$id)` will output a haystack to your screen in which you'll be quite unable to find any possible rare duplicate needles.*

Comment: This question and it's answers are unlike the question listed as a duplicate. This question asks to return the values that are duplicates. The "duplicate" question posted seems to just remove duplicates, so you don't know which values/rows they are.

Comment: I agree - the current question is not a duplicate of the marked question. The current question in fact only asks to return duplicate values of a vector (only `vocabulary$id` is there to check as we see in the chosen answer). The chosen answer won't help if we want to check whole dataframe rows for duplicates and the `$id` column is not there. The marked question on the other hand asks how to return duplicate rows of a dataframe.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You could use `table`, i.e.

```
n_occur <- data.frame(table(vocabulary$id))
```

gives you a data frame with a list of `id`s and the number of times they occurred.

```
n_occur[n_occur$Freq > 1,]
```

tells you which `id`s occurred more than once.

```
vocabulary[vocabulary$id %in% n_occur$Var1[n_occur$Freq > 1],]
```

returns the records with more than one occurrence.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I like them all (so +1 for each), and I learned a lot from each of them. I'm choosing this answer, because (1) it works without installing a new library and (2) because I find the logic behind it simple and elegant.

Comment: now that you have found the duplicated rows by id. can you now add a suffix like 234.A, 234.B etc. which will make them unique

Comment: To make values unique you can use the function make.unique from stringr package.

Comment: an alternative using dplyr to identify the duplicated `var`s. 
`df %>% group_by(var) %>% summarise(n=sum(n())) %>% filter(n>1) `

Comment: @JessicaBurnett More simply : `df %>% group_by(var) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% filter(n>1)`

Answer (score 78):

This will give you duplicate rows:

```
vocabulary[duplicated(vocabulary$id),]
```

This will give you the number of duplicates:

```
dim(vocabulary[duplicated(vocabulary$id),])[1]
```

Example:

```
vocabulary2 <-rbind(vocabulary,vocabulary[1,]) #creates a duplicate at the end
vocabulary2[duplicated(vocabulary2$id),]
#            id year    sex education vocabulary
#21639 20040001 2004 Female         9          3
dim(vocabulary2[duplicated(vocabulary2$id),])[1]
#[1] 1 #=1 duplicate
```

### EDIT

OK, with the additional information, here's what you should do: `duplicated` has a `fromLast` option which allows you to get duplicates from the end. If you combine this with the normal `duplicated`, you get all duplicates. The following example adds duplicates to the original vocabulary object (line 1 is duplicated twice and line 5 is duplicated once). I then use `table` to get the total number of duplicates per ID.

```
#Create vocabulary object with duplicates
voc.dups <-rbind(vocabulary,vocabulary[1,],vocabulary[1,],vocabulary[5,])

#List duplicates
dups <-voc.dups[duplicated(voc.dups$id)|duplicated(voc.dups$id, fromLast=TRUE),]
dups
#            id year    sex education vocabulary
#1     20040001 2004 Female         9          3
#5     20040008 2004   Male        14          1
#21639 20040001 2004 Female         9          3
#21640 20040001 2004 Female         9          3
#51000 20040008 2004   Male        14          1

#Count duplicates by id
table(dups$id)
#20040001 20040008 
#       3        2
```

Comment: For counting the number of dups, I was planning on suggesting `sum(duplicated(vocabulary$id))`, which seems simpler to me.

Comment: @Joran: Yes, your solution would also work.

Comment: This approach is _significantly_ faster than the one using the table in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 32):

Here, I summarize a few ways which may return different results to your question, so be careful:

```
# First assign your "id"s to an R object.
# Here's a hypothetical example:
id <- c("a","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","d")

#To return ALL MINUS ONE duplicated values:
id[duplicated(id)]
## [1] "b" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d"

#To return ALL duplicated values by specifying fromLast argument:
id[duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast=TRUE)]
## [1] "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d" "d"

#Yet another way to return ALL duplicated values, using %in% operator:
id[ id %in% id[duplicated(id)] ]
## [1] "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d" "d"
```

Hope these help. Good luck.

Comment: Nice. For the last approach, the call to unique() is not needed.

Comment: @David C. could you explain the third approach `duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast=TRUE)` ?

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini `duplicate` assigns the second, third, fourth... occurrences as TRUE. To mark all duplicated elements as TRUE, you need to count backwards as well. The *logical OR* operator inclusively allows that. Try a simple example: `x = c(1,1); duplicated(x); duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)`

Comment: I tested the different options from David C.: `id[ id %in% id[duplicated(id)] ]` is about 15% faster than the 'or' version on my dataset. It would be nice if package dplyr added a function like:  `repeated <- function(.x){ .x %in% .x[duplicated(.x)] }` since you have to compare all duplicates so often to de-duplicate a dataset.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a `data.table` solution that will list the duplicates along with the number of duplications (will be 1 if there are 2 copies, and so on - you can adjust that to suit your needs):

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(vocabulary)

dt[duplicated(id), cbind(.SD[1], number = .N), by = id]
```

Comment: I like this answer... but as a novice R user I'm trying to figure out what the .SD[1] and .N means?

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh I'd start here - https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Answer (score 6):

A terser way, either with `rev` :

```
x[!(!duplicated(x) & rev(!duplicated(rev(x))))]
```

... rather than `fromLast`:

```
x[!(!duplicated(x) & !duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE))]
```

... and as a helper function to provide either logical vector or elements from original vector :

```
duplicates <- function(x, as.bool = FALSE) {
    is.dup <- !(!duplicated(x) & rev(!duplicated(rev(x))))
    if (as.bool) { is.dup } else { x[is.dup] }
}
```

Treating vectors as data frames to pass to `table` is handy but can get difficult to read, and the `data.table` solution is fine but I'd prefer base R solutions for dealing with simple vectors like IDs.