# How to determine the uniqueness of each column values in its own dynamic range?

Tags: r

Assuming my dataframe has one column, I wish to add another column to indicate if my ith element is unique within the first i elements. The results I want is:

```
c1  c2

1    1   
2    1   
3    1   
2    0   
1    0
```

For example, 1 is unique in `{1}`, 2 is unique in `{1,2}`, 3 is unique in `{1,2,3}`, 2 is not unique in `{1,2,3,2}`, 1 is not unique in `{1,2,3,2,1}`.

Here is my code, but is runs extremely slow given I have nearly 1 million rows.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
k <- sum(df$C1[1:i]==df$C1[i]))
if(k>1){df[i,"C2"]=0}
else{df[i,"C2"]=1}
}
```

Is there a quicker way of achieving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate values in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905425/find-duplicate-values-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
x$c2 = as.numeric(! duplicated(x$c1))
```

Or, if you prefer more explicit code (I do, but it’s slower in this case):

```
x$c2 = ifelse(duplicated(x$c1), 0, 1)
```