# Select multiple duplicate rows based on specific values in next column

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

This is a follow up question to Kikapp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905425/find-duplicate-values-in-r).

I want to remove participant IDs which lack all the time-points. In other way around, I want to select rows which have all the four time (11, 21, 31, 41). See the sample data [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0vng9zjelyrkuv/df.csv?dl=0)

Here is my try based on Kikapp's answer. For some reason, it doesn't work. Let me know how to make it better.

```
data2 <- df[df$ID %in% names(table(df$ID))[table(df$ID) > 3],]
```

I get 4695 rows or objects or IDs for `time == 11`, `time == 21`,`time == 41` while 4693 for `time == 31`; however, I want they should be equal.

Comment: Try: `do.call(rbind,Filter(function(x) {
    length(unique(x[,2])) == 4
},split(df, df$ID)))`.

Comment: or `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% dplyr::filter(length(unique(time)) == 4) %>% data.frame()` with `dplyr`.

Comment: @Abdou - Thanks! First code did not work. Second gives same result as my data2 code. I get two less rows with `time==31`. Actually all four time-points (11,21,31,41) should have same number of IDs or rows or objects. With `data2 <- df[df$ID %in% names(table(df$ID))[table(df$ID) > 3],] ` code or yours `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% dplyr::filter(length(unique(time)) == 4) %>% data.frame()` code, I get 4695 rows or objects or IDs for 11, 21,41 while 4693 for 31 time.

Comment: Both the code snippets I provided do the same exact thing, so I am not sure what you mean by "_First code did not work_". It looks like you have 2 rows in your data that have `time` values of `32`. You did not mention that there are rows with values of `32` for `time`.

Comment: First code took quite long time, so I stopped it. Good point. `which(grepl(32, df$time))` gave me two places where `time == 32` (5629, 12602). Writing mistake, thanks! `df$time[df$time == 32] <- 31` worked. How did you do it? Great work!

Comment: I will write up an answer to explain how I found that there were rows with `32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` for this task for a much faster result:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(length(unique(time)) == 4) %>% 
    data.frame()
```

However, when you get the counts of `ID`'s for each `time` value you will find out that there are `32`'s hidden there (2 rows in total):

```
df1 %>% group_by(time) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(Counts = n()) %>% 
    data.frame()

#Output:
time Counts
 11   4695  
 21   4695  
 31   4693  
 32      2  
 41   4695
```

This shows that you have 2 rows with values of `32`. As it turns out, that was due to a typo on your part. So you can change them with `df$time[df$time == 32] <- 31` and run the code again.

I hope this was helpful.

Thanks!