# Find duplicate registers in R

Tags: r

I have an excel file with a list of emails and channels that collected it. How can I know how many emails per channel are duplicated using R and automate it (every time I import a different file just have to run it and get the results ) ?

Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905425/find-duplicate-values-in-r)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, this post helps me count the number of repeated emails but doesn't tell how can I group the count based on each channel.. am I right? :) sorry for the basic knowledge !

Comment: It would be for the best to go through some R tutorials. There are many ways of doing this. You could split the data by channel and find duplicates, or perhaps calculate the difference between unique and full set for each channel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "df" dataframe has the relevant variables under the names "channel" and "email", then:

To get the number of unique channel-email pairs:

```
dim(unique(df[c("channel", "email")]))[1]
```

To get the sum of all channel-email observations:

```
sum(table(df$channel, df$email))
```

To get the number of duplicates, simply subtract the former from the later:

```
sum(table(df$channel, df$email)) - dim(unique(df[c("channel", "email")]))[1]
```