# In R, how can I create subset data frame with all duplicate observations?

Tags: r

Lot's of questions out there touching the topic of duplicate observations but none of them worked for me so far.

In [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905425/find-duplicate-values-in-r) I learned how to select all duplicates from a vector.

```
# vector
id <- c("a","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","d")

#To return ALL duplicated values by specifying fromLast argument:
id[duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast=TRUE)]
## [1] "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d" "d"

#Yet another way to return ALL duplicated values, using %in% operator:
id[id %in% unique(id[duplicated(id)])]
## [1] "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d" "d"
```

Now having a data frame like this one:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
                  y = c(5, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
                  z = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
```

How could I select all observations that simultaneously have duplicate values of x and y, irrespective of z?

Comment: If the word `simultaneously` has some meaning , none of the answers below has taken that into consideration. If it does not then it is duplicate of the above question marked by @thelatemail.

Comment: @RonakShah perhaps it wasn't greatest choice of word and didn't mean more than `in the same time`

Comment: @thelatemail I missed this one! :/ Indeed does what I need too so if the answers are duplicate the question could be closed I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(x,y) %>% filter(n()>1) 

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#     x     y      z
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fctr>
#1    1     5      a
#2    1     5      b
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `data.table` like so:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
# selects all (x,y) pairs that occur more than once
dat[ , if (.N > 1L) .SD, by = .(x, y)]
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R

```
dat[ave(paste(dat$x,dat$y),dat$y,FUN=function(x) length(x))>1,]
  x y z
1 1 5 a
2 1 5 b
```