# search number falls in between range of numbers

Tags: r

I have these tables below that consists of a million rows and here i want to see if there is an overlap between Table 1 Target start- table 2 Target start, and so on with target end. How can i achieve this in R?

**Table 1** Target start  and Target ends (numerics)

```
TargetStart TargetEnd
7756        8357
35598       35009
9954126     9954371
9954126     9954346
9954126     10115435
```

**Table2**  Target start  and Target ends (numerics)

```
Target_Start  Target_End        
7000           10000        
23184775       23190099 
900000         1000000      
23157928       23165621 
23157410       23158724
```

**Desired table** would consist of the status overlaps

```
Target_Start  Target_End    Overlaps
7000          10000         yes
23184775      23190099      no
90000         1000000       yes
23157928       23165621     no
23157410      23158724      no
```

Please anyone can you guys help me in this?
thanks

p/s: i made some correction on the typo i made previously

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905425/find-duplicate-values-in-r

Comment: While trying to solve such a problem, you must know if your tables are sorted and if there is a possibility that Target_End[tuple]>Target_Start[next_tuple].

Comment: The table is well sorted and as it is..

Comment: what do you mean by overlap here? how are you calculating that?

Comment: im sorry but what i mean is that whether the value in table 1 is within the range in table 2. overlaps means the value is the same or within that range..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table::inrange` like this - note that you most likely have a typo in `Table 1` and the result you expected in `Desired Table` based on the actual inputs is incorrect

```
cbind(tbl1, tbl2) %>%
  mutate(Overlaps = as.logical(pmax(data.table::inrange(TargetStart, Target_Start, Target_End), data.table::inrange(TargetEnd, Target_Start, Target_End))))

  # TargetStart TargetEnd Target_Start Target_End Overlaps
# 1        7756      8357         7000      10000     TRUE
# 2       35598     35009     23184775   23190099    FALSE
# 3     9954126   9954371        90000     100000    FALSE
# 4     9954126   9954346     23157928   23165621    FALSE
# 5     9954126  10115435     23157410   23158724    FALSE
```

Data

```
tbl1 <- read.table(text="TargetStart TargetEnd
7756        8357
35598       35009
9954126     9954371
9954126     9954346
9954126     10115435", header=TRUE)

tbl2 <- read.table(text="Target_Start  Target_End        
7000           10000        
23184775       23190099 
90000          100000       
23157928       23165621 
23157410       23158724", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the data is as it is  and is so random , i know. lol.

Comment: Can you look at row 3 - the answer should be `no` but you indicated it should be `yes`

Comment: yup, my bad,it was a typo.That was one that i typed to show how it should be -without that typo of course. so about your answer, cbind(tbl1, tbl2) %>%
  mutate(Overlaps = as.logical(pmax(data.table::inrange(TargetStart, Target_Start, Target_End), data.table::inrange(TargetEnd, Target_Start, Target_End))))
-those should be in one line?

Comment: I am sorry im a newbie in programming and R

Comment: It can be one line or separated by a newline like `cbind(...,...) %>% \newline mutate(...)`

Comment: I found the error that says **Error: could not find function "%>%"** why is that happened?

Comment: Load the tidyverse: `library(tidyverse)`