# Verify if there are duplicated String IDs in R

Tags: r, string, duplicates

I was looking for duplicated IDs (string) in my dataframe, and if it's true, change for a sequence.
I tried using the `duplicate(x)` method but does not seem to find anyone (there are duplicates in my csv). I also saw this web in S.O: [Find duplicate values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905425/find-duplicate-values-in-r) and nothing happened apparently.

This is my code so far:

```
library(stringr)
if (duplicated(census$CS_ID)==TRUE){
  new_CS <- sprintf("CS%d",seq(1:length(census$CS_ID)-1))
  census$CS_ID <- str_replace_all(census$CS_ID, "^.*$", new_CS)
}
```

I think the main problem is the *==TRUE* condition, where maybe it should be if there is any TRUE in the `duplicate()` clause and not such a whole.

This is a sample of my csv

```
 CS_ID (str)
 CS620
 CS621
 CS622
 CS624
 CS624     
 CS625
 CS626
 CS627
```

Thank you for any help! =)

Comment: Could you show the expected output from the sample?

Comment: Duplicated returns a vector the same length as the input.  If you want any duplicates, try any(duplicated(census$CS_ID)).

Comment: Try `census$CS_ID_unique <- make.unique(census$CS_ID)`

Comment: That was it @Arthur, now works perfectly. Thank you so much to you all!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, CS_ID_new := ifelse(rowid(CS_ID) > 1, paste(CS_ID, rowid(CS_ID)), CS_ID)][]
#    CS_ID CS_ID_new
# 1: CS620     CS620
# 2: CS621     CS621
# 3: CS622     CS622
# 4: CS624     CS624
# 5: CS624   CS624 2
# 6: CS625     CS625
# 7: CS626     CS626
# 8: CS627     CS627
```